# How to set max file size for commits in subversion

Tags: svn

Hallo,

is it possible to limit the file size for commits in subversion server?

Some guys upload large swf files in the subversion repository. I would like to limit the file size to 30 MB.

Thanks
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a pre-commit hook on the Subversion repository.  See [this page](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook) for a good start on that.

Comment: Thanks. This gives a direction. But this doesn't solve my problem, because I can't code python.
Someone has a ready pre-commit hook script for this case?

Comment: http://beaversource.oregonstate.edu/projects/admin/browser/management/master-svn/trunk/hooks/pre-commit/max-commit-size.py should do what you want.  It's still Python, but it shouldn't need much editing.  Between this and the other page I linked to you should be well on your way.

Comment: this seems to need pysvn

Comment: The current URL for this script is https://code.oregonstate.edu/svn/admin/management/master-svn/trunk/hooks/pre-commit/max-commit-size.py